# Booting with a Fujitsu Siemens

Tags: boot, 12.04, system-installation

I have a laptop of Fujitsu Siemens lifebook series with centrino duo 1.6 ghz processor and 2 GB ram and 20 GB hard drive so can I install Ubuntu 12.04 on this machine, plus I have two non encryptable drives showing on its My Computer and i want to remove them so do I have to remove them during installation, if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's related to recoverable system images or something for diagnostics. Please check in user manuals or call vendor. 
You may damage a SW setup on the laptop if removed.

Regards.